# Datatables server side script and search on every column using SQL MATCH COMMAND

Tags: php, mysql, search, datatables, server-side

I'm trying to use MATCH SQL command with a server side datatables script but somehow the datatables is unable to work, it does not find any results but if I copy and paste the query output to any sql client, it works fine and find the expected results (matches).

To put you in context, this is what i've done right now:

1-Create a FULLTEXT index on the database with the columns that will be used for the search:

ALTER TABLE site ADD FULLTEXT INDEX fulltext_index_site (id, title, domain);

2-Changed the logic for search strings in the server side script:

```
$searchValue = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['search']['value']); // Search value

## Search
$searchQuery = " ";
if($searchValue != ''){
   $searchQuery = " AND MATCH(id, title, domain) AGAINST('".$searchValue."' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
      }
```

3-I've changed the query to use the MATCH command:

```
select id, title, domain
from site
where 1 ".$searchQuery."
```

4-But if I go and search something on the client side, no results are found...I've also checked the payload and the search[value] is with the value to be searched but does not return any result. Even I've put an echo and get the output:

```
select id, title, domain
from site
where 1 AND MATCH(id, title, domain) AGAINST('test' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

And works fine on the sql client, it returns all the rows that matches with the 'test' pattern but on datatables just say "No results found".

5-I've even tried using a LIKE OR approach but that is not properly working because the pattern must be a coincidence on every column searched.

e.g.

```
## Search
$searchQuery = " ";
if($searchValue != ''){
   $searchQuery = " AND (id LIKE '%".$searchValue."%' OR title LIKE '%".$searchValue."%' OR domain LIKE '%".$searchValue."%')";
}
```

I'm a little burned out with this and run out of ideas why does not work on the server-side script but instead works on a sql client.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try echo'ing your select query to make sure it is being form the way you expect. Also, you need some SQL injection protection.

Comment: hi Simon, yes, i've tested that as I mention, also i got somehow sorted out the sql inyection with this $searchValue = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['search']['value']);

Comment: My bad - Didn't read it properly. Just an idea, maybe there's a difference in your default character set for your client connection and server connection. I can't see  anything else that would make a difference. See 'taking into account the current character set of the connection' on https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_real_escape_string.asp/php/func_mysqli_real_escape_string.asp.

Comment: no worries, i think it might be related on the response composition:

I got while ($row = $result->fetch()) { to build the data used by datatables, if i remove that it works but only display one row when no search is found.

Comment: I found the issue! i got a repeated $row = $result->fetch_assoc() before the while ($row = $result->fetch()) {  that was smashing the rows! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue! i got a repeated
`$row = $result->fetch_assoc()` before the `while ($row = $result->fetch())` that was smashing the rows! thanks.